# Application specific injection in a framework

Tags: java, dependency-injection, configuration

I'd like to create a reuseable application independent user registration framework. In the Data Acces Layer it has to create the app specific user entity. I've created a UserFactory interface to inject the app specific factory instance.

```
public interface UserFactory
{
  public UserWithRoles createUser();
}

@Dependent
class UserWithRolesDAL
{
  @Inject
  private UserFactory userFactory;
  ...
}
```

NetBeans says: "Unsatisfied dependency:no beans matches the injection point" I know I should use a Qualifier. But in this case it won't be an app independent framework. How can I use a UserFactory implementation which depends on app configuration?

The language is Java. It takes place in an EJB modul of a WabApp. The UserWithRolesDAL itself is injected by CDI into a stateless session bean.

As highstakes recommended bellow I did it:

```
@Alternatives
@ApplicationScoped
class XUserFactory implements UserFactory
{
  ...
}
```

And registered it in the beans.xml:

```
<alternatives>
    <class>x.XUserFactory</class>
</alternatives>
```

But the message is the same! Why?

Comment: Please mention the programming language. Java?

Comment: I forgot it. But as the annotations suggest the language is Java. And it takes place in an EJB modul of a WabApp. The UserWithRolesDAL itself is injected by CDI into a stateless session bean. I will update the qustion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. The error after the bean alternative registration in the beans.xml caused by the @ApplicationScoped annotation from the wrong package.

The wrong one:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
```

The right one:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Why use a factory when you can user @Produces to generate the user?
2. If you have multiple factory implementations you should mark them as @Alternative and in the beans.xml of each of your app you can specify the implementation used:
   https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjsdf.html

Edit: one side note, if you have all these applications completely separate outside of an EAR I do not think CDI supports cross deployment injection, so this could also be the issue

Comment: I have no implementation in the abstract framework. But in the application wich uses will be only one implementation. Or more for the test cases in the development phase. I just want to make it reuseable in a separate form, not to use by many apps.

Comment: I marked the implementation by the @Alternative annotation and I registered the class in the beans.xml. But the message is the same :(

Comment: if you only have one implementation then this is not the problem. It is most likely your deployment structure. If you post it along with your beans.xml locations that would help.